# How to make domain accessible with www on apache 2.4

Tags: apache, ubuntu, laravel

I want my laravel app accessible with or without `www` on the url. like [http://laracasts.com][1]. when I hit http://example.com it works. But when I hit http://www.example.com, or http://www.example.com/contact I'm getting 404 error. How can I solve this? I'm using `apache 2.4.7` on Ubuntu and here's my `example.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ServerAdmin foo@bar.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/public

    <Directory /var/www/myproject/public/>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

and here's my `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.1.1 example
127.0.0.1 localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
xxxx::0 ip6-localnet
xxxx::0 ip6-mcastprefix
xxxx::1 ip6-allnodes
xxxx::2 ip6-allrouters
xxxx::3 ip6-allhosts
```

and `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

about server stuff, i'm noobs.

Answer (score 0):

Your apache configuration is correct. However, you need to enable the rewrite module:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you use a registered domain, this is enough. If you just use a "local" domain for development, you have to add this dumping domain into your hosts file at `/etc/hosts`. For example, when working with local environment, I usually use a domain `.local`, I'll add this line to make the domain `example.local` work:

```
127.0.0.1 example.local
```

Comment: Still nothing's happen after i run`sudo a2enmod rewrite` and `sudo service apache2 restart` :(

Comment: Add these line into your `/etc/hosts` file: `127.0.0.1 example.com` and `127.0.0.1 www.example.com`.

Comment: a, did you enable this site? does `example.com.conf` exist inside the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include all the possible domain/subdomain name combinations that you would like to use in your hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

In regards to `http://www.example.com/contact` does `http://example.com/contact` work?